# can't read data correctly after comPort_DataReceived without SLEEP()

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am doing a serialport control test but have no idea why I have to call sleep() before read just right after serialport DataReceived event triggered, like this

```
void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(33); // <-- necessary to put, 33 is the lowest number in my PC
    int cntBytes = myComPort.BytesToRead; // length = 24 
    myComPort.Read(toBuffer, 0, curtBytes); // complete data (25 20 32 30 2C 56 41 2C 2D 35 35 0D 0A 25 20 32 30 2C 56 41 2C 46 0D 0A)
}
```

but if I do read without sleep in advance, I will get trouble reading it. The complete string will be devided into several times

```
void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    //Thread.Sleep(33); // NO sleep here
    int cntBytes = myComPort.BytesToRead; // length = 4 
    myComPort.Read(toBuffer, 0, curtBytes); // incomplete data (25 20 32 30)
}
```

it troubles me a lot. very appreciate if u know any clue.

Comment: This is entirely normal.  Use ReadLine() instead of Read() to trivially solve your problem.

Comment: before I call read()/readline(), u can see the number of BytesToRead is different

Comment: and my communication is prefer hex mode (including non-Ascii chars) so it's better to use Bytes reading instead of string

Comment: possible duplicate of [SerialPort Class issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142647/serialport-class-issues)