# Serial port c# how to interpret data received

Tags: c#, serial-port

[image]

When i read the serial port using c# in a console application, this is the output i get.
Does anyone know how i should read this data so it's readable by a human.

The data that should be received is like : 6025 1045 1806 116 0000000 and GPS coördinates.
I know its a bit vague, but i am new to serial port programming and would like to know how to move on.This is the code i have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace ClarityListener
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClarityWarning("Starting communication...");
            SerialPort Dave = new SerialPort("COM1");
            Dave.BaudRate = 9600;
            Dave.Parity = Parity.Odd;
            Dave.DataBits = 8;
            Dave.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            Dave.Handshake = Handshake.None;


             Dave.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
             try
             {
             Dave.Open();
             ClarityMssg("Connected!\n");
             }
             catch
             {
                 ClarityError("Problem!\n");
             }

             ClarityWarning("Press any key to shutdown program");
             Console.WriteLine();
             Console.ReadKey();
             Dave.Close();

         }

         private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
         {
             SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
             string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
             ClarityWarning("Data received : ");
             ClarityWarning(indata.ToString() + "\n");

         }

         private static void ClarityMssg(string message)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        }

        private static void ClarityError(string message)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        }

        private static void ClarityWarning(string message)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show how you're setting up the communication with the Serial Port?
(are you using .NET's `SerialPort` class?) (Are you even running .NET? or is this MONO?)

Comment: I Will post my code in a minute. I am indeed using .NET's SerialPort class. I am using .NET 4.0

Comment: A Baudrate mismatch is possible but not very likely.  More likely is that the device is sending binary data.  Contact the device vendor for support.

Comment: @thefiloe geen idee waar je het over hebt.

Comment: See the answer provided by Hans Passant in this post which is similar. It's about issues with weird characters and truncated messages. His code block and explanations were very helpful. [SerialPort Class issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142647/serialport-class-issues?rq=1) - [alykins](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3198872/alykins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data received over a channel is a stream of bytes, being it over tcp/ip or serial or read from a file. Programming against a serial port is not that different/difficult as there is no hitech black magic involved.

Just dumping the received bytes to the console assuming that it is ascii is not the way to go. Although it can give you a head-start in determining what's send.

First check the parameters set on the receiving serial-port. Most devices are using 9600 baud, no parity, 8, 1 stopbit. If there is a mismatch data gets mangled. Check the specs from the manual of the device.

Do you know in what format the data is send? Are numbers converted to ascii literals before sending or are they send as int32 in 4 bytes? 
What is the flow control of the source? 
Are there control/command bytes in or between the messages?
In short: know the protocol used by the sender. Check the documentation and as a last resort  call the vendor / distributor.

Comment: I have contacted the company who supplied to system to my company. The baudrate etc... are correct. It appears the data is transmitted as a byte stream (format is <STX><DATA><CRC><ETX>) They even supplied a screenshot from the transfered data (will link here). So i am a little bit closer to a solution, but still no clue on where to go from here. [IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/2ajcpww.png [/IMG]

Answer (score 1):

First things that come to mind :

make sure the parity, stop bits and baud rate of your serial port reader are configured to match the requirements of the device sending the data.

Also make sure your serial device is indeed sending ASCII encoded text. 
(this is the standard for NMEA, a protocol mostly used for devices like this, but there is no guarantee your device adheres the the standard 100%)